# NSCFString Memory Leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been solving a lot of memory leaks but have been unsuccessful in solving this one. There are tons of NSCF memory leaks coming due to [NSCFString substringWithRange:]. I have been checking all the String allocations and have released all of them at appropriate places.  The responsible library: Foundation.

Has anyone encountered this problem before? Can anyone suggest me as how I should takle this issue?

Thanks,

Lakshmie

Comment: Under what circumstances is this occuring? Do you have a code sample that reproduces it?

Comment: My bad! I solved this problem. But there is a leak in General Block-3584. I am aware that it has been reported that this block is leaky and is a bug in the framework. But I just wanted to know if CTFont is one of those leaky things in the framework. CTFont --> UIKit (Responsible Library).

Thanks!

Comment: General Block-3584 just means a malloc of 3584 bytes. It is not itself a component of any framework.

Regardless, judging from info on the web, it appears to be a CFNetwork issue and its not entirely clear that it's a leak -- just that the Leaks tool *thinks* its a leak.

In any case, this one probably isn't your fault and you can ignore it.

Comment: You should provide your own answer to this question in an actual answer in stead of in the comments.  That way it gets removed from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

General Block-3584 just means a malloc of 3584 bytes. It is not itself a component of any framework. Regardless, judging from info on the web, it appears to be a CFNetwork issue and its not entirely clear that it's a leak -- just that the Leaks tool thinks its a leak. In any case, this one probably isn't your fault and you can ignore it.  -  Matt

Answer (score 1):

using the class methods of NSString, such as [NSString stringWithString:@"hi"] will leak, since memory was never allocated - you dont see an alloc in there, ya?. the proper way is:

```
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"hi"];
myIvarProperty = temp;
[temp release];
```

Comment: That's not the proper way at all. I think you mean `self.myIvarProperty`, otherwise `myIvarProperty` will reference something that you don't own.

Comment: Good answer, but I want to know why ?